# Stop page refresh after filtering grid in mvc.grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcgrid.net

I am using Mvc.Grid ([Grid.MVC5](http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Home/Installation)), I want to stop its page refresh which is automatically called after using any filter. Is it possible?

View :-

```
@model IEnumerable< MVC6_Grid_with_filters.Models.SchemeMaster>
@using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid;
@{
    Layout = null;
}

< link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/MvcGrid/mvc-grid.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
< script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">< /script>
< script src="~/Scripts/MvcGrid/mvc-grid.js" type="text/javascript">< /script>

@(Html
.Grid(Model)
.Build(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(c => c.SchemeID).Titled("SchemeID");
    columns.Add(c => c.SchemeName).Titled("SchemeName");
    columns.Add(c => c.city).Titled("City Name");
    columns.Add(o => o.CompanyName).Titled("Company Name");
    columns.Add(c => c.Createddate, "Createddate").Titled("Date");
    columns.Add(c => c.Married).Titled("Married");
})
.Filterable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable()
)
<script>
    $('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Html.AjaxGrid` with your partial view

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Only main string query values will be visible here.
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult IndexGrid()
{
    var list = GetSchemeMasters(); // Your custom list method to get SchemeMasters
    return PartialView("YourPartialView", PeopleRepository.GetPeople());
}
```

Main View:

```
@Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("YourPartialAction"))
```

Your Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable< MVC6_Grid_with_filters.Models.SchemeMaster>

@(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Build(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(c => c.SchemeID).Titled("SchemeID");
        columns.Add(c => c.SchemeName).Titled("SchemeName");
        columns.Add(c => c.city).Titled("City Name");
        columns.Add(o => o.CompanyName).Titled("Company Name");
        columns.Add(c => c.Createddate, "Createddate").Titled("Date");
        columns.Add(c => c.Married).Titled("Married");
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
)
```

Comment: thanks @Hasan, actually I have used this already but after using it i dont get filters overs grid,  and if i call  $('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid() on partial view then it again refreshes page..

Comment: now, i have only paging and sorting in my page which not refreshing url but i want filters as well..

Comment: can you try to add 
columns.Add(model => model.YourField).Titled("YourField").Filterable(true);

Comment: thanks @Hasan, actually it was mvc-grid.css problem I write it in bundle and now its working..

Comment: Can we call @Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("YourPartialAction")) using jquery???

Comment: I did not try it before. You can try something like this
 @Html.Raw(Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("YourPartialAction"))) in jquery but i am not sure whether it works